# Defining custom emacs find-grep shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, shell, emacs

Emacs supports `M-x find-grep` which searches for a string and opens two buffers. One buffer with the search results and other one opens the file which contains the search string.

Currently `M-x find-grep` expands to following command `Run find (like this): find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e  {} +`.

How can I modify find-grep (or define a new shortcut?) which adds more options to grep and find commands

(e.g. Ignore log files or include only java files `find . -iname '*.java'`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify `find-grep`. Write your own, similar, command. Start with a copy of its code, if you like. Instead of the part where it invokes program `find` to implement `find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e () +`, substitute your own preferred command line. Simplify and adjust to taste (e.g., `find . -iname '*.java'`).

Both `find` and `grep` have their own languages (syntax) -- `find`, in particular. To use them, you need to know (1) what you are trying to do and (2) how to do that using their languages.

Unless you specify exactly what you are trying to do, the only help we can give you here is general guidance about invoking `find` and `grep` from Emacs.  For that, the `find-grep` code is a good guide -- see above.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

How do I go about writing my find-grep. Say `java-find-grep` which includes an extra option to find command ( `-iname '*.java'`)

Comment: As I said, copy the definition of `find-grep`, change the command name of the copy to `java-find-grep`, and substitute the `find` command you want for the one used in the `find-grep` definition. To find the definition of `find-grep`, use `C-h f find-grep RET`.

Comment: `C-h f find-grep RET` gives a description of what find-grep but I am not able to find the source code for that function.

Comment: Click the file name (`grep.el`) near top of the `C-h f` help buffer. That should take you to the command definition. If not then try `M-x find-library grep.el` to get to the file. (If you don't have the source file then you don't have a complete Emacs installation.)

Comment: n.b. There are other Q&As about not being able to find the source code, so search for those if need be.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to prefix `find-grep`, i.e. `C-u M-x find-grep`.  It allows you to edit the command line before executing it.

If you want to permanently change it, you can define a wrapper.  This is for `rgrep`, but `find-grep` should be similar.

```
(defvar grep-context-lines 2
  "Default number of context lines (non-matching lines before and
  after the matching line) for `rgrep-context'.")

(defun rgrep-context (arg)
  "Like `rgrep', but adds a '-C' parameter to get context lines around matches.

Default number of context lines is `grep-context-lines', and can
be specified with a numeric prefix."
  (interactive "p")
  (setq arg (or arg grep-context-lines))
  (let ((grep-find-template
         (format "find <D> <X> -type f <F> -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep <C> -nH -C %d -e <R>"
                 arg))
        grep-host-defaults-alist
        current-prefix-arg)
    (call-interactively 'rgrep)))
```

Note: your `grep-find-template` might be different; you're probably best off if you modify your default rather than just copying this one.  The default is generated by `grep-compute-defaults`.

Comment: On my system (mac osx, emacs 25.3.1) I had to tweak the format for grep-find-template. This setup doesn't use xargs and was failing. Adjusting it to better match the current contents of grep-find-tempate fixed this easily. My format spec now reads (format "find <D> <X> -type f <F> -exec grep <C> -nH -C %d -e <R> {} +" arg) As emacs rgrep uses an external program (grep) this may well be an issue for other systems too.

Comment: @Iain Thanks, the logic to generate the default is pretty involved, and can clearly vary from system to system.  I made a note to modify your default instead of just copying mine.